# FormType ChoiceType (select) data preset not working in view Symfony 3.4

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4, symfony3.x

In a Symfony 3.4 Application I have defined a MyFormType class with a ChoiceType element like that

```
$builder->add(
    'my_field_1',
    ChoiceType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'My Label',
        'placeholder' => 'nothing selected',
        'choices' => $choicesArray,
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => true,
        'data' => $choicesPreset,
    )
);
```

In a Controller I create the form passing in the needed object to preset data and then I pass the created view to a twig template.
In the template the form is rendered OK. Everything works except that the preset value of the ChoiceType select element is not set. The field is rendered with the placeholder option selected.

All other elements of the same form do load their preset values without problems. None of them is a ChoiceType though.

When debugging I see that the preset value is correct when creating the form class and also it is set to the field (I am not sure though which properties exactly have to be set in the FormBuilder element).
While debugging the ChoiceType preset value looks OK in the Controller as well.
However the template renders the placeholder.

I am not sure how to debug twig templates and if I knew I wouldn't know what to look for.
Any hints on what could go wrong here are very welcome.

**EDIT:**

While checking the choices and preset values aI discovered that the problem is actualy not coming from the form field itself or any of its options but from a data transformer.
I have this line directly below the code postet above:

```
$builder->get('my_entity')->addModelTransformer( $this->myEntityToNumberTransformer );
```

When deleting this line the preset value works (not the transformer though. Obviously...). So the question is acutaly: Why does the data transformer interfere with the preset value setup?

Comment: You could add example of $choicesArray and example of $choicesPreset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choice field default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771945/choice-field-default-value)

Comment: @revengeance thanks. I wanted to paste the vars and figured that they are not a problem - the used data transformer is though. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the field or the preset values but in the data transformer I mentioned in my edit. Fixing the data transformer fixed the problem with no preset values as well.